# onSucess returns undefined for metadata param when inside Vue view but not inside component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, plaid

I have a vue component that is for Plaid Link that calls a function/action in my Vuex store named `onSuccess` that should call my backend API to exchange the public token for an access token and send some data about the link to the backend. However it seems like the `metadata` param is coming back as `undefined` when `console.log()` inside my Vuex store but if I do it inside the component itself I have no issues.

Vuex code

```
onSuccess({ commit }, public_token, metadata) {
        console.log(public_token, metadata)
        commit('SET_PUBLIC_TOKEN', public_token);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Vue.axios.post('/plaid/exchange_public_token', {
                public_token,
            })
            .then(() => {
                resolve();
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
            });
        })
    },
```

Code inside my view script section

```
computed: {
            ...mapState({
                plaid: state => state.plaid
            })
        }, 
        
        methods: {
            ...mapActions({
                onLoad: 'onLoad',
                onExit: 'onExit',
                onEvent: 'onEvent',
                onSuccess: 'onSuccess',
            }),
            
        },

        mounted() {
            this.onLoad();
        },
```

Code inside my view template section

```
 <PlaidLink
                clientName="Plaid App"
                env="sandbox"
                :link_token="plaid.link_token"
                :products="['auth','transactions']"
                :onLoad='onLoad'
                :onSuccess='onSuccess'
                :onExit='onExit'
                :onEvent='onEvent'
                >
```

Code inside my component that is for plaid.create with other helper functions removed

```
this.linkHandler = this.plaid.create({
            clientName: this.clientName,
            env: this.env,
            isWebview: this.isWebview,
            key: this.public_key,
            product: this.products,
            receivedRedirectUri: this.receivedRedirectUri,
            token: this.link_token,
            webhook: this.webhook,
            onLoad: function() {
              // Optional, called when Link loads
              self.onLoad()
            },
            onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
              // Send the public_token to your app server.
              // The metadata object contains info about the institution the
              // user selected and the account ID or IDs, if the
              // Select Account view is enabled.
              /* eslint-disable no-console */
              console.log(metadata)
              self.onSuccess(public_token, metadata)
            },
            onExit: function(err, metadata) {
              // Storing this information can be helpful for support.
              self.onExit(err, metadata)
            },
            onEvent: function(eventName, metadata) {
              self.onEvent(eventName, metadata)
            }
          });
```

Comment: There can't be more than 1 arg in action function. Destructure a payload if you need several values

Comment: @EstusFlask Do you mean I should put them together in an object? Sorry not great with Vue mostly a backend guy and got that code from an npm package. Should I write my own component for it instead?

Comment: See the docs, action function is not variadic, the second param is payload object, vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions , everything you pass to an action needs to be its properties

Comment: @EstusFlask Thanks, I guess I am a little confused still. Would that just mean I add the object next to the dipatching of the action? Where would the state come from? It very much seems like a black box of where that data is coming from/passed in. Almost as if I need a helper to call the proper action and instead bind my component to a different action directly in my view

Comment: Should be `onSuccess({ commit }, { public_token, metadata }) {` and `self.onSuccess({ public_token, metadata })` to use payload object. This is totally about function signature

Comment: @EstusFlask that worked thank you. If you want to add that as an answer I'd gladly accept that for you to get points if you care about them

Comment: Sure. Glad it sorted out the problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vuex actions and mutations can have 1 optional payload parameter, [see the usage](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions). In case there's a need to pass multiple values, they need to be the properties of payload object.

In order to make it concise, use object literal shorthand syntax:

```
self.onSuccess({ public_token, metadata })
```

And object destructuring syntax:

```
onSuccess({ commit }, { public_token, metadata }) { ... }
```